# Отправка фотографии боты обратной связи

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота сбора отзывов и наткнулся на проблему. Есть вопрос где человеку предлагается написать коментарий и при желании добавить фото, после чего вся собранная информация отправляется администрации. Но если гость добавляет 2 или более фото, то во первых ему пишется столько раз сообщение что отзыв отправлен, сколько было фото, во вторых администрации приходит полный отзыв столько раз сколько было фото. Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

```
     async def question5(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Напишите ваш комментарий(можно с фото)')
    await state.set_state(feedback.text)

@dp.message(feedback.text)
async def question5_1(message: types.Message,  state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    if message.text != None:
        await state.update_data(text=message.text)
        await state.update_data(photo=None)
    if message.photo != None:
        await state.update_data(text=message.caption)
        await state.update_data(photo=message.photo[-1].file_id)
    await fin(message, state,bot)



async def fin(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    data = await state.get_data()
    func.join(chat_id=message.from_user.id)
    q.execute(f"SELECT block FROM users WHERE user_id = {message.from_user.id}")
    result = q.fetchone()
    if result[0] == 0:
            await message.answer('Сообщение успешно отправленно!')
            for admin_id in admin:
                if data['photo'] !=None: await bot.send_photo(admin_id,data['photo'])
                await bot.send_message(admin_id, f"<b>Получен новый вопрос!</b>\n"
                                                 f"<b>От:</b> {message.from_user.username}\n"
                                                 f"<b>ID: </b>{message.chat.id}\n"
                                                 f"<b>Чистота:</b> {data['cleanness']}\n"
                                                 f"<b>Чистота:</b> {data['level']}\n"
                                                 f"<b>Чистота:</b> {data['quality']}\n"
                                                 f"<b>Чистота:</b> {data['speed']}\n"
                                                 f"<b>Чистота:</b> {data['text']}\n"
                                                   ,reply_markup=kb.fun(message.chat.id), parse_mode='HTML')
    else:
        await message.answer('Вы заблокированны в боте.')
```